# How to splice two LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, linked-list, splice

I have a `List<bar>` of `LinkedList<foo>`:

```
int x = y;
List<LinkedList<foo>> list = new List<LinkedList<foo>>(x);
```

I want to be able to **move** all elements of a `LinkedList<foo>` of `list` into another without create new list or nodes. This is why I choose a `LinkedList<foo>` type. In C++, I could use [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

At the end, only one element of `list` will not be empty.

My problem is that I can't find anyway to do this, I only found method that copy two `LinkedList<foo>` into one or similar.

My research so far (this is not what I want):

- [How does one add a LinkedList<T> to a LinkedList<T> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094445/how-does-one-add-a-linkedlistt-to-a-linkedlistt-in-c#1094493)
- [Append LinkedList to the end of another LinkedList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409201/append-linkedlist-to-the-end-of-another-linkedlist?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Note: I don't care about data order, I just need performance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. A `List<LinkedList<foo>>` would be similar to C++'s `std::vector<std::list<foo>>`. How is `List` relevant to the question?

Comment: @milleniumbug I add List for the context maybe it's useless. But indeed I would like a method splice on LinkedList<T>, or a solution that use an other container that would implement splice and have O(1) on this operation.

Comment: Also: are the left-hand side and the right-hand side different types like the example code says they are? And what about `List<bar>` and `LinkedList<foo>`? Not to mention, C++'s `std::list::splice` is O(n) too (but probably still fast) because the rhs list has to maintain the `size()`.

Comment: [`LinkedList<T>.AddLast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132176) accepts a `LinkedListNode<T>`, and another line is needed to remove the nodes from the source.

Comment: If you need this to be O(1), you'd need a linked list class which has a a O(n) `.Count`. There's no such built-in class in .NET

Comment: @Slai Not perfect but I suppose this is very close to what I want, this was simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If with "I just need performance" you mean you need the splice operation to be O(1), then, as far as I know, this is not possible with .NET.

However, you could create your own type that behaves like a `LinkedList<T>` and that supports such a splice operation. Of course it is not nice to implement functionality that's already present, but on the other hand a linked list is not that complicated.

Or you could create a type that wraps `List<LinkedList<T>>` (or something similar) and supports the operations you need. E.g. `LinkedList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection<T>`, and implementing these on a wrapper for `List<LinkedList<T>>` is just a few lines of relatively simple code, and the splice operation would be almost for free.